# Response.Write on shared hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, response

On my asp.net site, I build about 2-3 MB csv file and then try to send it as Response, so I do:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                sb.AppendLine("Name\tType\tNumber\tStatus");

                foreach (string county in GetCounties())
                {
                    List<StationItem> list = GetStationItems(county);

                    foreach (StationItem item in list)
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine(
                            string.Format(
                            "{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}",
                            item.Name, item.Type, item.Number, item.Status));

                    }
                }

                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Stations.csv");
                Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
                Response.End();
```

It works perfect on my localhost, but when I upload it to shared hosting, page brakes. IE says: Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage, Chrome says: 
he webpage at Page.aspx?auto=1 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error 103 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED): Unknown error.

What problem it could be, appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: You use a page, and its very possible the `Response.Clear()` to not been able to clear the IIS headers, if some headers have all ready been send by any other module. I suggest to try a handler and see if works.

Comment: You can also try to use `Response.Flush()`, just before the `.End()`

Comment: I tried, but same problem :(

Comment: Have you tried with a minimally sized test CSV just to see if it also fails?  Could help to pinpoint problem.

Comment: Yes, with minimally sized it works.

Comment: Try saving the file to disk, the use TransmitFile to send it. I prefer this way as I give also a link to the client which expires in an hour as an added feature.

Comment: @ihorko Instead of `AppendHeader` can you try `AddHeader` although they are same, sometimes these things happens. PLus set the `Response.Buffer` to `true` and tell me if it works or not.

Comment: Yes, please post as answer